# html 5 working with input date

Tags: jquery, html, date, input, opera

opera and chrome show a nice date picker for input type date so my question is does the calender display have an id so i can hide it once the user selects a date ?

--the way it currently is that you have to click outside of the control for it to hide
... so was hacking at it and i got it to simulate ... `var $focused = $(':focus'); $focused.toggle(); $focused.toggle();`
ughhh i hate js but any way i was wondering if theres some documentation on this date control to change and customize it. i have read the w3 specs but nothing of much help. or maybe a better way to do it thru jquery.

thanks for the help

Comment: You can give it an ID and onblur disable/hide it from view?

Comment: In what way do you want to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of the datepicker if you will use input type date.

You can use jQuery datepicker, if you want to hide datepicker popup after selecting date, by using onSelect option.